# Watir-Webdriver - Div from a frame never stops loading when running the tests

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am working on a automation project using cucumber, watir-webdriver and ruby.
I am having some big issues with a div that loads without stopping.
The web page on which I am working on contains a Frame that has inside a report generating form. After selecting the settings from the form and generating the report, under the form a div with the results should load. There are many options and elements for which the report can be generated. If I select the options to generate a smaller report, every thing works correctly and the Div loads as expected. But when generating a larger report the Div with results loads without stopping (no results appear, the actual Div with results appears only after the loading process is finished).

If I do these manually every thing works properly. I added a "wait_until_present(500)" but this is useless.

Is there an issue with loading Divs inside a frame on watir-webdriver?
Or is there a thing that causes the application to work wrong when the tests are running?

It seems like the application is stalling if it has to wait to much for the Div to load. I repeat, this cannot be reproduced manually.

Does some one has any idea of why this is happening? :(

Thank you.

Comment: Ask someone to place a bounty for you :)

Comment: Oh yeah! :).. If this will help, I'll do it. But really, I need some advice on this. :(

Comment: You are lucky guy. The only thing you need to do to know the answer is to take the webpage that messes it up and send it to the Watir team, they will appreciate bug report and'll tell you whether it's really something with Watir.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this problem. I will do just that. Thank you Boris :)